# What is the RegExp that replace all the "." occurrences inside "<code>" tag

Tags: regex

I would like to replace all the dots inside the HTML tag `<code>` with the word " dot ".

If I do like this it will change only the first occurrence.
I would like to change them all.

```javascript
const str = 'Some text <code class="foo">this.is.a.class</code> and <code>this.another.thing</code>';

const res = str.replaceAll(/(<code[^>]*>.*?)(\.)(.*?<\/code>)/g, "$1 dot $3");

console.log(res);

// Some text <code class="foo">this dot is.a.class</code> and <code>this dot another.thing</code>
```

Why it is changing only the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `String#replace` method with a callback function:

```js
const str = 'Some text <code class="foo">this.is.a.class</code> and <code>this.another.thing</code>';
const res = str.replaceAll(/(<code[^>]*>)([\s\S]*?<\/code>)/g, (_,x,y) => `${x}${y.replaceAll(".", " dot ")}`);
console.log(res);
```

The `(<code[^>]*>)([\s\S]*?<\/code>)` regex matches and captures the open `code` tag into Group 1 (`x` variable), and then captures any zero or more chars as few as possible and then the close `code` tag into Group 2 (`y` variable). When replacing, all dots in `y` (Group 2 captured value) are replaced with `DOT` inside the arrow function.

Note that `[\s\S]` matches any chars including line break chars, `.` does not match line break chars (at least by default).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the callback function.